# web.GetFolder() - value does not fall within the expected range. Sharepoint 2010

Tags: document-library, folder

Below is the code to check if folder exist in doc library on a subsite and if not than create it.

```
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(sharePointSite))//"http://testsite.dev"))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/bdox"))
                            {
                                // Get doc library
                                SPList documentLibrary = web.Lists[documentLibraryName];
                                CopyFolder(parentfolder, documentLibrary, web);
                            }
                        }

CopyFolder(parentfolder, documentLibrary, web)
{
      string SharepointfolderURL = "/Shared Documents/TestFolder/";
      SPFolder newFolder = web.GetFolder(SharepointfolderURL);
      if (!newFolder.Exists)
      {
          web.Folders.Add(SharepointfolderURL);
          // Save changes
          web.Update();
      }

}
```

I am getting the an error on `SPFolder newFolder = web.GetFolder(SharepointfolderURL);` as `value does not fall within the expected range`.

The code works fine for `RootWeb` please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code solved the issue

```
SPFolder newFolder = web.GetFolder("/bdox"+SharepointfolderURL);
```

Comment: This solves it, because `web.GetFolder` expects a __server__ relative path and not a site relative path.